# Getting error while inject ng-bootstrap in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Can't able to inject ng-bootstrap in angular module. I'm getting error.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jsapi.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

And my module I have injected like this,

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngRoute",'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

But Still i am getting error. I am using angular 1.4.2 version.

[image]

Comment: `ng-bootstrap` and `ui.bootstrap` are different and are not part of angularjs. You would need to add a script for it as well

Answer (score 1):

You are missing references to angular-bootstrap and the css . Add it there

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
```